# How To Call Methods Using Self Like [self Method_Name]; when Method name very Long Like -(void)imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am new to iPhone development. I want to know that how to call a method using `self` like:

```
[self Method_Name];
```

when the method name is very Long Like

```
- (void)imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *)picker
        didFinishPickingImage: (UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo: (NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    ...
}
```

W want to call  `imagePickerController` method using `self`. I tried calling it with:

```
 [self imagePickerController]; // Crash Here
```

But the code always crashes on this line. How can I call the method?

Comment: This is UIImagePickerController's delegate method..and It will call it self, You should not have to call it manually.. Just implement UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.. For more details http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

Comment: How to call This i need to call this method using "self"?

Comment: But why you want to call this method manually as it will call automatically.

Comment: i use if else conditon in another method on that i have to call this because in this method - (void)imagePickerController: ......  i use alertview n alertview  if(on1==True){UIalertview *alrt .....} so in another method on==True and after this i have to call [self imagePickerController]; so that UIAlertview will show...

Comment: Read ["Object Messaging"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW6)

Comment: Dude the name of the method is "imagePickerController - **didFinishPickingImage**" dont call it manually! write other methods that will be called when you need, or declare a public BOOL variable, change it's value in the if-else condition and just read the value in `imagePickerController:pickerdidFinishPickingImage:` when it gets called by the pickerControllerDelegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write the definition of the method .m file as follows:

```
    #import "classname.h"

    @implementation classname

    @synthesis variable1 = <variable1_>;

    @synthesis .....;

    -(void)imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *)picker
    didFinishPickingImage: (UIImage *)image
    editingInfo: (NSDictionary *)editingInfo {

      // Your code for this method comes here.

    }
```

(No need to declare the method in .h file.)

Then call the method using 'self' where you needed as follows:

```
    [self imagePickerController: UIImagePickerControllerObject
    didFinishPickingImage: UIImageObject
    editingInfo: NSDictionaryObject];
```

Answer (score 3):

`imagePickerController` is not method name. The method name is

```
imagePickerController: didFinishPickingImage:  editingInfo:
```

It has three arguments and you have to pass arguments.

When you call method in the same class, you can write as following as

```
[self imagePickerController: pickerParameter
    didFinishPickingImage: imageParameter
    editingInfo: editingInfoParameter];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[self imagePickerController: pickerParameter
    didFinishPickingImage: imageParameter
    editingInfo: editingInfoParameter];
```

xxxParameters are the parameters you want to pass to the method .

Answer (score 2):

this will be called automatically. 
but answering to ur ques about how to call such methods, it should be done like

```
[self imagePickerController: picker
didFinishPickingImage: image
editingInfo: editingInfo];
```

but it's not required to call this delegate method. its called automatically

hope it helps. happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are calling method like `[self method_name]`. Then method should be declared in (.h) file of that class (if you want to access this method in another class otherwise no need to declare in .h) and that method should be defined in (.m) file of same class. You can call any method like this..

```
// in .h file

- (void)imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingImage: (UIImage *)image
editingInfo: (NSDictionary *)editingInfo;

// cal this in .m as following  

[self imagePickerController:pickerController
didFinishPickingImage: imageNamed
editingInfo: editDictionary ];
```

Comment: Not necessarily the header file but yeah if instance is created in a different method you want to get the object methods exposed. +1 as all answers are almost the same and i have upvoted all.

Comment: ya you are right dear...!! Any declaration of method in .h is for accessing that method in another class.